# how to test stateFlows when emitting multiple items

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines, turbine

I'm trying to write an unit test for following method in ViewModel Class, but test is always failing  on assert items,

expected:<UiState(showLoading=true,...

Actual   :UiState(showLoading=false...,

not sure why test is not waiting for item to emit.

```
 class TestViewModel(private val signInUseCase: SignInUseCase) {
        
        
            private val mutableUiState = MutableStateFlow(AuthContract.UiState())
            val uiState: StateFlow<tAuthContract.UiState> = mutableUiState.asStateFlow()
        
            fun simulateAPICall() {
                viewModelScope.launch {
        
                    mutableUiState.update(showLoading = true)
                    delay(100)
                    //signInUseCase.invoke("username","password")
        
                    mutableUiState.update(
                        showLoading = false,
                    )
                }
            }
        
        }
        //----------------
        class TestViewModelTest {
        
            @MockK
            private lateinit var signInUseCase: SignInUseCase
        
            private lateinit var viewModel: TestViewModel
        
            @get:Rule
            val coroutineTestRule = CoroutineTestRule(UnconfinedTestDispatcher())
        
            @Before
            fun setup() {
                MockKAnnotations.init(this)
                val context: Context = mockk(relaxed = true)
        
                viewModel = TestViewModel(
                    signInUseCase
                )
            }
        
            @Test
            fun `test SignInFlow`() = runTest {
                viewModel.uiState.test {
                    viewModel.simulateAPICall()
                
        
                val expectedLoading = AuthContract.UiState(showLoading = true)
                Assert.assertEquals(expectedLoading, awaitItem())
        
                val expectedSignInSuccess = AuthContract.UiState(
                    showLoading = false,
                )
                Assert.assertEquals(expectedSignInSuccess, awaitItem())
            }
           }
        
        }
        //----------------
        
        @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
        class CoroutineTestRule(private val testDispatcher: TestDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()) :
            TestWatcher() {
        
            override fun starting(description: Description) {
                super.starting(description)
                Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
            }
        
            override fun finished(description: Description) {
                super.finished(description)
                Dispatchers.resetMain()
            }
        }
    
    kotlinx-coroutines-test= 1.6.4
    mockkVersion= 1.13.5
    turbine="0.12.1"
```

Comment: It's suspicious that you're calling `awaitItem()` outside of the `test {}` block...

Comment: i'm doing it in test block , i just made typo when copying to SO